# How to best maintain a sorted list from a stream of integers?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, lists, streaming-algorithm

If I have an incoming stream of integers how can I best maintain a sorted list of them? The only way I can think of is to binary search for the position and shifting the remaining elements to the right. This would amount to $O(N + \log N)$ time. Is there a better data structure that can help me achieve the same in better time? I know we can use a Balanced Binary Search Tree with $O(\log N)$ insertions but I would like to have efficient access on the list.

Comment: B-tree.........

Comment: Does it allow random access?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding elements to a sorted array](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/930/adding-elements-to-a-sorted-array)

Comment: @AndrewScott I would like to advise you to avoid using random access to mean efficient access. You can just say "efficient access" or "fast access". Here is the conventional meaning of [random access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) in computer science.

Comment: Important edit - maintaining sorted list will be O(N^2). Any sort of balanced tree will be O(N*logN)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A balanced binary search tree can support access to arbitrary elements in $O(\log N)$ time per access.  Augment the data structure to store, in each node, the number of values stored in the subtree under that node.  Then you can find the $i$th largest value in the list in $O(\log N)$ time as well; thus, all basic operations can be done in $O(\log N)$ time.

Comment: @D.W. thank you. That is indeed an efficient solution. As far as the random access is concerned, I meant I only want to pick the $i$th element fairly efficiently.